# Connect to Apache times out randomly

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout, telnet, intermittent

We are trying to set up an Apache server on a remote machine, but we experience strange behaviour. Checking with `telnet remote.machine 80`, one of these things happen randomly:

- Connect and serve content normally (no delay)
- Connect after a long pause
- Connect normally, then time out without response
- Timeout on connect

Once connected, the request seems to be processed normally. These things do not occur if I connect from that machine directly to `localhost 80`.

The Apache is dedicated, as is the server it runs on (runs only this one application, no-one else is using it for anything else). I am not an administrator of the remote site, and I do not know the network architecture over there, but apparently it's firewalled: (HTTP port is open, SSH port is IP-restricted, most others are closed).

If there was any *one* pattern, I might have some ideas, but this variety of symptoms baffles me. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Apache is 2.2; Server version is:

```
Linux version 2.6.9-22.ELsmp (bhcompile@porky.build.redhat.com)
(gcc version 3.4.4 20050721 (Red Hat 3.4.4-2)) #1 SMP
Mon Sep 19 18:32:14 EDT 2005
```

**UPDATE:** The administrators over there found the error - apparently, they had some anti-intrusion heuristics software running. When they disabled it, everything started working as it should. Thank you for thinking with me, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you have described seems a little inconsistent.  To me this sounds like there is possibly an IP conflict (Although if you are connected via ssh I would expect problems there as well if this is the case), but could be other things as well.  I would recommend you try to get the network administrator of the remote site involved.

Comment: "Little inconsistent" is an understatement :) We'll probably do exactly that, but I'm trying to see if there's anything in Apache (mis)configuration that might do this before we hand it over to the network people. Thanks.

Comment: If you ssh in a few times does it always work or do you see problems there as well?

Comment: Could also be maybe to many open file descriptors or something like that as well.  Anything in the apache error.log?

Comment: I didn't find anything suspicious in `error_log` - the worst thing are `File does not exist`s, like `favicon.ico`. I couldn't see anything that would suggest to me some abnormal operation. I did not experience any strangeness with `ssh`.